# Equivalent of buildout for linux OS dependencies?

Tags: python, linux, deployment, system-administration

I'm planning on using buildout to build a webapp. I want to use lesscss though, and for that I need to install node.js.

Is there an equivalent of buildout for setting up an OS to install dependencies that I can't install using pip? Or is it possible to do this using buildout somehow taking into account the fact that I don't want to execute my buildout script as root?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For managing the package dependencies of your OS, perhaps you should look at using tools like [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) and [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/).

Such tools would enable you to manage the following OS resources:

- Packages
- Users
- Configuration files

Might also be possible to let these tools install your application by invoking buildout (or pip)